# How to set public read-only access for one Dropbox file

Tags: permissions, dropbox

Is it possible to create a dropbox account with two types of users:

1. The owner (me) with full permissions (read/write).
2. The public (members of a club) with read-only access to the one file in the box.

The club is getting new members every day. So we will need a person to welcome the new member, ask for her e-mail address, then add her to the list of people, who shares the file.

My idea is to create an account with a short name, that is easy to remember, and give that name to the new member. This account should then hold the LINK to the "public" file in the other Dropbox account. My paranoia is that malicious members could delete, or edit that.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

1. Make a Dropbox account in the usual way.
2. Put the file(s) in your public folder.
3. Right-click the file, select copy public link.
4. Share that link. [E.g. this.](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/78841909/How%20to%20use%20the%20Public%20folder.txt)
5. Repeat until done.

Comment: The problem is, that the club is getting new members every day. So we will need a person to welcome the new member, ask for her e-mail address, then add her to the list of people, who shares the file... My idea is to create an account with a short name, that is easy to remember, and give that name to the new member. This account should then hold the LINK to the "public" file in the other Dropbox account. My paranoia is that malicious members could delete, or edit

Comment: It would be too easy for an angry member to make this solution useless.

Comment: @Otto Did you try it? The public link gives them access to view/download the file, not save changes back to the original file. This is "read-only" access and they don't even need to be added to the dropbox account for this -- you just send them the link to view the file.

Comment: Also, you don't actually *have* to put the file in the public folder, as the public link can be generated for any file in your dropbox.

Comment: @Otto I may not have made it clear but the link to the txt file in this answer is in my personal Dropbox. You can access it without any account if you have the link and your access is read-only.

Comment: Sorry I was not clear enough in my question. We are a LOT of members of a community. Members come and go everyday, so maintaining a mailing list, is not an option.

Comment: Sorry I was not clear enough in my question. We are a LOT of members of a community. Members come and go everyday, so maintaining a mailing list, is not an option. If one member gets angry and malicious with the club, he could enter the public box to delete or edit the LINK, that has been pasted there. This would stop other members of the club, to use the LINK. Of course you can REPASTE the link into the box. Dependent on how angry the person is, this could be a SYSYFOS job - never ending. See my point?

Comment: @Otto, the file in the DropBox is read only. The link is only a link, they could type it in the address bar of their browser if they wanted. The link simply points to that file. No matter how angry someone is, the file in your DropBox is safe and the link remains active until the DropBox owner deletes the file, i.e. you.